# SQLite, insert or ignore based on result of a union subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite, insert, union, exists

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3, field4) VALUES (@field1, @field2, @field3, @field4) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
     SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE field1 = @field1 AND field2 = @field2
     UNION
     SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE field1 = @field2 AND field2 = @field1
);
```

The above code does not work.

When I have entry in database like:

'**black**' '**sheep**' 'eats' 'grass'

And I try to insert new entry like:

**'sheep'** **'black'** 'eats' 'grass'

Or entry like:

**'black'** **'sheep'**' 'eats' 'watermelon'

I don't want anything to go into database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `INSERT ... SELECT` if you want a `WHERE` clause.
Also you can simplify the `WHERE` clause by avoiding `UNION`:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3, field4) 
SELECT @field1, @field2, @field3, @field4 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM table 
  WHERE (field1, field2) = (@field1, @field2) 
     OR (field1, field2) = (@field2, @field1)
)
```

If your version of SQLite is 3.31.0+, it is better to create `GENERATED` columns on which you can base a `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename(
  field1 text, 
  field2 text, 
  field3 text, 
  field4 text,
  un_min text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MIN(field1, field2)),
  un_max text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MAX(field1, field2)),
  UNIQUE(un_min, un_max)
);
```

Now you can insert new rows with INSERT OR IGNORE:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO table (field1, field2, field3, field4) VALUES (@field1, @field2, @field3, @field4);
```

Unfortunately SQLite does not allow the addition of constraints to an existing table.
You must recreate the table (you can find instructions on how to do it here: [ALTER TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) or here: [SQLite ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-alter-table/))

Comment: Thanks a lot! This turned out to be rather slow though. I guess I should have created a unique index for this, e.g. have black+sheep+sheep+black and turn it into md5 or something

Comment: What is your version of SQLite?

Comment: 1.0.113. Took around a minute to insert 30k records this way

Comment: @NickFarsi No, this is not the version of SQLite. Execute `SELECT sqlite_version()`. If it is 3.31.0 then there is a solution with generated columns to create a unique constraint.

Comment: It is v. 3.32.1

Comment: @NickFarsi ok, I will post a solution with a unique constraint.

Comment: @NickFarsi se my edited answer. If you can recreate the table it will be better to use a unique constraint.